# How to open a .scd2 type file

Tags: python, pandas, scd

I have first time encoutered a .scd2 type file. I downloaded this file from a sensor database. And I need to view the measeurements to make analysis of te data. I know SCD means slowly changing dimensions but I have no idea how to open this type of data using python. It would be great if I could convert this file type to ".csv" or ".xlsx" to work with pandas. I searched the internet but I cannot find any information regarding this extension nor how to dealwith it.

[image]

Comment: Have you opened the file in a text editor to look at its format? From [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/processing-a-slowly-changing-dimension-type-2-using-pyspark-in-aws-9f5013a36902) it looks like it's simply a fixed-width tabular format in plain text.

Comment: yes I did, the file opens but it's not readable. It's encrypted I guess and I have read that webpage you shared :).